# Excel 2016: Compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope, when there isn't

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

OS: Win 7 Enterprise, Service Pack 1

Excel: Microsoft(R) Excel(R) 2016 MSO (16.0.9001.2102) 64-Bit, No AddIns

The issue started out with having two similar function declarations, however, even with modifications the compiler error persists.

Process: a brand new workbook, no COM Addins, added a module, added the functions below

Debug > Compile VBA project

Message: `Compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope.` with `functionA` highlighted.

This is **ALL** the code there is in the workbook.

Changing `functionA` to anything, gives the same error.

Removing an argument, for example: `beginRow as Long,` gives the same error.

Thank you in advance for any insight or suggestions.

```
Option Explicit

Private Function functionA(beginROW As Long, endRow As Long, inCOL As Long, lookFor As String, foundRow As Long, endRow As Long) As Boolean
End Function

Private Function functionB(beginROW As Long, endRow As Long, inCOL As Long, lookFor As String, foundRow As Long, endRow As Long) As Boolean
End Function
```

Comment: You have *two* instances of `endRow` in each function declaration - one as the 2nd argument and one as the last.

Comment: Thank you. Always good to have a second set of eyes on the problem. Overlooking the obvious. And it's Friday, late Friday.

Comment: As I commented to someone earlier, it's Friday, so we all get a pass :)